# How to import multiple Excel sheets into SQL tables using C#?

Tags: c#, sql, excel, datatable

I need to import a multiple Excel sheets into multiple SQL tables (according to their table) by clicking a C# button control.

Comment: For us to help you need to tell us what you have tried already, and what part of that are having an issue with. I'd recommend taking the [tour], reading [ask] and then providing a [mcve] if you can. As it is, your question is particularly broad.

Comment: @Diado, Sorry for the inconvenience for not providing the Correct information, I have try to import using oldbeComand but i can insert only one table at time

Answer (score 0):

at frist please install nuget  Spire.XLS for example 'Install-Package Spire.XLS -Version 
9.6.7'
 now you can use code below
   you should 
        using Spire.xls 
  in your namespace

```
 public static DataTable ReadExcelFromPath(string path,int sheetNumber)
    {
        DataTable dt = null;
        try
        {
            //Load the Excel file
            using (Workbook workbook = new Workbook())
            {
                workbook.LoadFromFile(path);

                //Get the  worksheet
                Worksheet sheet = workbook.Worksheets[sheetNumber];
                //Export data to data table
                dt = sheet.ExportDataTable();

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.ToString());

        }
        return dt;
    }


 public static List<DataTable> ReadAllExcelSheetFromPath(string path)
    {
        List<DataTable> dt_list = new List<DataTable>();
        try
        {
            //Load the Excel file
            using (Workbook workbook = new Workbook())
            {
                workbook.LoadFromFile(path);
                for (int i = 0; i < workbook.Worksheets.Count; i++)
                { //Get the first worksheet
                    Worksheet sheet = workbook.Worksheets[i];
                    //Export data to data table
                    dt_list.Add( sheet.ExportDataTable());
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.ToString());

        }
        return dt_list;
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Use **EPPlus** nuget package.

Documentation link:
https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/wiki/Reading-and-Writing-Data

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: Please check @Diado's link for the downvote explanation.